# expat module issue on Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am using `sublime text 2.0.2` on a *Debian testing x64*, and whenever I try to use the `xml ElementTree` in a plugin script, it just fails :

```
ImportError: No module named expat; use SimpleXMLTreeBuilder instead
```

The Simple *XMLTreeBuilder* doesn't seem to work either..

But with my system's `python ( 2.7.5 and 2.6 )` *ElementTree* works find.

What can I do to fix that ?

Comment: have you tried using Sublime Text 3?

Comment: No I am not using sublime text 3 while it's still in beta.